# missing template rails problem with JSON rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Has anyone come across this error before? I've looked online and couldn't find much information, perhaps I didn't render my JSON correctly?

> Missing template answer/results, application/results with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/Minhaj/Desktop/my_survey/my_survey/app/views" * "/Users/Minhaj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.5.0/app/views"

Here is the code. If there is an error, help will be appreciated in fixing it.

```
  def create
    @answer = current_survey.answers.create(question_id: question, choice_id: choice)
    redirect_to question_survey_path(current_survey)
  end

  def results
    @choices = choices_hash
    @results = questions.map do |question|
      {
        question.question => CountChoicesService.call(question.id)
      }
    end
    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { render :nothing => true, :status => 204 }
      format.json { render json: @results }

    end
  end

  private

  def question
    @question ||= params[:question]
  end

  def choice
    @choice ||= params[:choice]
  end

  def choices
    @choices ||= Array.wrap(Choice.all)
  end

  def choices_hash
    choices_hash = {}
    choices.each { |choice| choices_hash[choice.id] = choice.choice }
    choices_hash
  end

  def questions
    @questions ||= Array.wrap(Question.all)
  end
end
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: You need to create a `view` named `results.html.erb` under `answers` namespace. You should have a directory structure like this `app/views/answers/`, go inside that and create `results.html.erb`

Comment: _Missing template answer/results_. This means either you need to `redirect` in the `results` action, or create a view like I explained above. Usually, we **redirect** on **success**.

Comment: I have a page for results.html.erb under answers directory like you said. How do I redirect however. Also what exactly do you mean by redirecting?

Comment: There is a typo, your directory name is not `answers` it's `answer`.Change it to `answers`

Comment: the name of my directory is answers. There is no typo.

Comment: What's your controller name ? The error says, it is looking for `results` under `answer` and not `answers`

Comment: my controller name is answer_controller.rb. This is my directory structure app/views/answers

Comment: Can you change it to `answers_controller`?

Comment: I am getting a routing error.

Comment: After `results` action is successful, what do you intend to do ? Do you want to go to another page or respond with json ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should look like, **controller name is plural**

Under your controller directory, you should have this

```
# app/controller/answers_controller.rb
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def results
  end
end
```

Now in the views directory,the view namespace should be the same as the controller name.

```
# app/views/answers/results.html.erb
<h1>Check if this works</h1>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :answers do
  collection/member do
    get :results
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are not returning. Rails will render the associated template for the action unless you return. Try wrapping your `render` calls in `return()`.

Side note, why are you using Array.wrap()? ActiveRecord’s `all` methods are array-like. They wait to execute the query until you actually try to iterate them, and then they act like an array. You shouldn’t need to make them an array. If you ever find that you do, you can call `.to_a` on them.

One thing to note about the active record record collection though, if you remove anything from its “array”, it will actually do a delete from the database, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error he is facing, it's a naming convention issue, he has named controller as `answer` which is singular and views namespace as `answers` which is plural and **Rails** cannot identify that.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna But render nothing true and render json should not be rendering any views... Am I missing something? Is the render json NOT going to just call `@results.to_json`?

Comment: Missing template means it knows where the controller is, but it can’t find the corresponding view for the action. And this is specifically using the html format, not json based on the error message.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but as per his comments, he is trying to render a view which he is already defined under `views/answers`, check his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107827/missing-template-rails-problem-with-json-rendering/52107933?noredirect=1#comment91166496_52107827). Hence in my answer, I just defined a method which by default should render a view for him.

Comment: Correct it knows where the controller is and the controller name is `answer_controller.rb`, but his views namespace is `answers`. Hence the template is not being found.

Comment: But it should not be using a template. It should be rendering nothing with a status of 204...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179149/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-nate).